# How to send an email with a form inside

Tags: html, forms, mailing

Is it possible to send an email with a form inside ?
We want to send an email to our subscribers with an input text inside the email to get a complementary information, I havn't seen this before, is it possible to do that ?
If yes, which problems could we meet with that solution ?

Comment: [This](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/) might be a good read for you

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is possible...

and even if it is, I wouldn't choose to do it.

You can not know what device your user will be on and if his mail client will support this.

If I were you, I'd just link them to the online form they have to fill. (You could use Google Docs for instance) or do it on your own website with an html form and write it to a database.

Why go through the pain of having to deal with hundrets of emails?